# Android O Fonts not working

Tags: android, fonts

I'm using Android O fonts in my app:

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 21

compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1
def android_arch_version = '1.0.0-alpha8'
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$android_arch_version"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$android_arch_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$android_arch_version"
```

And in xml I use

```
<...android:fontFamily="@font/sans_light"/>
```

This has no effect on the font, is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: I don't think you can use features from API 26 if your target SDK version is only 21.

Comment: @evanklicker: I have compileSdkVersion 26 
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
 Android OS version : Lollipop 
Attached 2 screen shots : https://ibb.co/cT4J9v - extending AppCompat (works fine) 

https://ibb.co/kJzkpv- extending LifecycleActivity (does not work)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Did you select that font in Android Studio, or did you type that yourself? A downloadable font needs a few more XML files, you should not type `<...android:fontFamily="@font/sans_light"/>` yourself.

Android Studio will generate the needed files for you automatically if follow this guide, especially the part "Using Downloadable Fonts via Android Studio and Google Play services" where they tell you to use the layout editor to select a font: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html

Comment: I did not type in the font.
If I extend my Activity from **AppCompatActivity the font works fine** -  ibb.co/cT4J9v
but, if I **extend LifecycleActivity the font does not work** - ibb.co/kJzkpv

Answer (score 0):

To use the FontInXml feature, below are the prerequisits:

1. You need to have Android Studio 3.0+ and Android SDK 8.0 (API 26+)
2. Gradle plugin version 3.0.0-beta4 or higher and Android plugin version 4.1 is required
3. It is recommended to have support library version 25.0+ in order to see the preview of fonts in Preview section of studio

Try this combination. For setup details, refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

This bug is fixed in the  android_arch_version = '1.0.0-alpha9'